# How do I create a 2d array with different starting values in the first row?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need help learning how to make a 2d array with different starting values in the first row, based on whatever the row is above it I then need it to double. 
Like this:

Week pop 1 pop 2 pop 3 pop 4 pop 5

0     10    100   500  1000  5000

1    20     200  1000  2000  10000

and to go 9 weeks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two For Loop will do the job. https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/multidimensional-array and https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int row = 9; // row
        int col = 5; // col
        int[][] results = new int[row][col]; // final results
        int[] firstvalues = new int[] {10,100,500,1000,5000};

        for(int a = 0 ; a < firstvalues.length; a++ ) {
            System.out.println(firstvalues[a]);
        }
        //first row to last row
        for(int i = 0;i < row; i++ ) {
            //first column to last column
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if(i==0) {
                    results[i][j] = (firstvalues[j]);
                } 
                    results[i][j] = (i + 1) * firstvalues[j];    
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++ ) {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.println("Element at row:" + i + " " + j + " " + results[i][j]);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer was, essentially, provided by @phyonemyatt, the following solves the issue of the calculation and provides a formatted output. Nonetheless, the basic approach is exactly that of @phonemyatt.

```
  public static void main(String []args){
    int row = 10; // row
    int col = 5; // col
    int[][] results = new int[row][col]; // final results

    // set the first row's starting values
    int[] firstvalues = new int[] {10,100,500,1000,5000};


    //first row to last row
    for(int i = 0;i < row; i++ ) {
        //first column to last column
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

            // if we are the first row, use the defined starting values
            if(i==0) {
                results[i][j] = (firstvalues[j]);
            } 
            else {
                // double from the row before
                results[i][j] = results[i-1][j] * 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // create the output, we use printf for formatting
    System.out.printf("%5s", "week  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("%10s", "Pop " + (i + 1));
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++ ) {
        System.out.printf("%4d  ", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

            System.out.printf("%10d", results[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

Output

```
 week       Pop 1     Pop 2     Pop 3     Pop 4     Pop 5  
    0          10       100       500      1000      5000  
    1          20       200      1000      2000     10000  
    2          40       400      2000      4000     20000
    3          80       800      4000      8000     40000
    4         160      1600      8000     16000     80000
    5         320      3200     16000     32000    160000
    6         640      6400     32000     64000    320000
    7        1280     12800     64000    128000    640000
    8        2560     25600    128000    256000   1280000
    9        5120     51200    256000    512000   2560000
```